# Does a photo asset url always stay the same?

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm using UIImagePickerController to get an asset URL for a photo from user's library. The URL I receive is similar to this:

> assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=02539CC5-CB7F-4792-B5C0-74DD63D274CA&ext=JPG

Is there a guarantee this URL stays the same for a photo until that photo is removed or modified?

Comment: Yes it will until that photo is removed or modified.